# delivery of custom digital product after purchase

Tags: paypal

Does anyone know if Paypal can deliver a customized digital product or custom download page following a customer payment?  I am looking to deliver a custom digital product immediately once it has been approved for and paid for by the client.

Comment: You should ask this question in a product forum. SO helps solving programming problems/errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can, please read the PayPal IPN documentation, which can be found [HERE](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)